# Arduino MKR GSM 1400 project - Establish call - Wait and hang call

Tags: arduino-ide, communication, gsm

I am implementing a GSM project using the Arduino MKR 1400 GSM board and I would like to achieve the following:

Establish a call to a specific number, wait for a certain amount of seconds and then hag the call. I have written the following test code in order to see how to manage it.

```
#include <MKRGSM.h>

// PIN Number
#define PINNUMBER ""

GSM gsmAccess;
GSMVoiceCall vcs;

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600); 

  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while(notConnected)
  {
    if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("GSM initialized.");

  if (vcs.voiceCall(char_array_number)) {
    Serial.println("Call established");
    delay(10000);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Something is going wrong");
  }

}

void loop()
{

}
```

Well, the call is established, the phone rings but the instructions inside the if statement won't get execute. Instead I get the following Serial Monitor output.

[image]

I don't really understand why that happens because since the call is stablished the first if statement would be executed. I would really appreciate any help, since this is like the final step of my project and been struggling for some time.